# Comparing elements in the value at two keys

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def equal_keys(d, key_one, key_two):
    for key, value in key_one.items():
        for key, value in key_two.items():
            pass
```

given a dictionary and two keys, how do we loop through each element in the value in both the
specified keys and filter out any elements that don't match from every key at that index.

ex.

```
>>> equal_keys({'i.year': ['1997', '1997'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003']}, 'i.year', 'j.year')
{'i.year': ['1997'], 'j.month': ['April'], 'i.month': ['April'], 'j.year': ['2003']}
```

so what it does:

```
{'i.year': ['1997', '1997'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003']}
```

the two specified keys as the parameters are i.year and j.year, so we compare the elements in both the key and check if they are equal. So the first element in i.year is 1997, and the first element in j.year is 1997, they are equal so we move on to the next element. The next element in i.year is 1997 and the next element in j.year is 2003, they are not equal so we delete every element in every key at that index, therefore we get:

```
 {'i.year': ['1997'], 'j.month': ['March'], 'i.month': ['March'], 'j.year': ['2003']}
```

While this does work:

```
def equal_keys(d, *keys):
    indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(zip(*(d[key] for key in keys)))
               if len(set(x)) == 1]
    return {key: [value[x] for x in indexes] for key, value in d.items()}
```

is there a way to write this is a similar nature to the beginning code, with three parameters, no zip, no imports, no *, or no one liner lines in the form like these:

```
{key: [value[x] for x in indexes] for key, value in dct.items()}
```

*pretty much a simple line by line easy to understand way*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much just unpacking what you've given, but will hopefully be easier to understand:

```
def matching_values_by_keys(d, key1, key2):
    # figure out which elements of each list to keep
    keep_indices = set()
    for index,value in enumerate(d[key1]):
        if value == d[key2][index]:
            keep_indices.add(index)

    # now go through each dictionary entry and keep the wanted elements
    new_d = {}
    for key,lst in d.items():
        new_lst = []
        for index,value in enumerate(lst):
            if index in keep_indices:
                new_lst.append(value)
        new_d[key] = new_lst

    return new_d
```

and when run as

```
matching_values_by_keys({'i.year': ['1997', '1997'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003']}, 'i.year', 'j.year')
```

returns

```
{'i.month': ['March'], 'i.year': ['1997'], 'j.month': ['March'], 'j.year': ['1997']}
```

which I think is the correct answer by your description ('March', not 'April' as given above).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is much easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, no import, no `zip`, no one-liners(except one ;-), `min`):

```
def equal_keys(d, *keys):

    indexes = []
    #get the length of shortest list
    min_ = min(len(d[x]) for x in keys)

    for i in xrange(min_):
        items = []         #collect items on same index in this list
        for key in keys:
            items.append(d[key][i])
        # If len(set(items)) != 1 means all items are not same, so add this
        # index to indexes
        if len(set(items)) != 1:
            indexes.append(i)

    dic = {}
    #Now iterate over each (key, value) pair and for each value
    #keep only those items that are present on the indices stored in indexes list.
    for k, v in d.items():
        dic[k] = []
        for i in indexes:
           dic[k].append(d[k][i])

    return dic
```

Comment: Thank you for this, can you explain this part: if len(set(items)) != 1:

Comment: @Sc4r A set can only contain unique keys, so if we pass the items received from the same indexes to it then and we can check whether all of them are same or not by checking the length of the set. `set(['1997', '2003', '1997'])` -- > `set(['2003', '1997'])`

All items same: `set(['1997', '1997', '1997'])` -- > `set(['1997'])`